# Only Mapping Nested Object of State to Props won't update Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I use `mapStateToProps` to get an nested Object from an object by Id. The problem is, the props don't get updated and componentDidUpdate won't fire when the redux store state changes.

Here are my reducers:

```
export const programmReducers = (state = initialState, action) => {
    let programms = state.programms;

    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.FETCH_CATEGORIES:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                categories: action.payload
            })
        case actionTypes.FETCH_PROGRAMM:
            programms[action.payload.id] = action.payload;
            console.log(programms);
            return {
                ...state,
                programms: Object.assign({}, programms)
            }
        case actionTypes.FETCH_PROGRAMM_COMPONENTS:
            programms[action.programmId].components = action.payload;
            console.log('Added Components')
            return {
                ...state,
                programms: Object.assign({}, programms)
            }
        case actionTypes.FETCH_PROGRAMM_SECTIONS:
            programms[action.programmId].sections = action.payload;
            console.log('Added Sections')
            return {
                ...state,
                programms: Object.assign({}, programms)
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Here is my components:

```
class ProgrammPage extends Component {

    static async getInitialProps({ store, query: {id} }) {
        if (!store.getState().programm.programms[id]) {
            console.log('Programm not! found');
            await store.dispatch(loadProgramm(id));
            await store.dispatch(loadProgrammComponents(id));
        } else {
            console.log('Programm found')
        }

        return {
            programmId: id
        }
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        if (this.props.user) {
            console.log('Loading init!');
            this.props.loadProgrammComponents(this.props.programmId)
            this.props.loadProgrammSections(this.props.programmId);
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        console.log('Update')
        if (!prevProps.user && this.props.user) {
            console.log('Loading update');
            this.props.loadProgrammComponents(this.props.programmId);
            this.props.loadProgrammSections(this.props.programmId);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Programm</h1>
                <h2>{this.props.programm.name}</h2>
                <h2>{this.props.programm.id}</h2>
                <h3>Components: {this.props.programm.components ? this.props.programm.components.length : 'None'}</h3>
                <h3>Sections: {this.props.programm.sections ? this.props.programm.sections.length : 'None'}</h3>
                <br></br>
                <h1>User: { this.props.user ? this.props.user.uid : 'None'}</h1>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.loadProgramm('ProgrammLevel2')}>Load Programm</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.loadProgrammComponents(this.props.programmId)}>Load Components</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        programm: state.programm.programms[ownProps.programmId],
        // programms: state.programm.programms <--- Fixed the problem
        user: state.auth.user
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
    loadProgramm,
    loadProgrammComponents,
    loadProgrammSections
}, dispatch)

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(ProgrammPage)
```

When the Reducer for `FETCH_PROGRAMM_COMPONENTS` or `FETCH_PROGRAMM_SECTIONS` changes the redux state, `componentDidUpdate` isn't called and the component doesn't dispay the changes.

The problem seems to be related to the `mapStateToProps`method, because, when I add `programms: state.programm.programms` everything works fine. However I don't need the whole programms object.

Why are doesn't the component recognize that the programm has updated when I map only a nested object to my props?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is within the `programmReducers`, your component doesn't rerender because you don't change the state.

After changing `mapStateToProps` you **need to make changes in your component.**

The next code probably breaks when you change `programms: state.programm.programms` to `programm: state.programm.programms[ownProps.programmId]`

```js
export const programmReducers = (state = initialState, action) => {
    let programms = state.programms;
    ...
}
```

So I'm guessing your reducers aren't doing what you intended.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I don't get what you think my error is. I also don't see a problem with my reducers